# Loading external class files without regard to class-paths or packages

Tags: java, classpath, classloader, urlclassloader

I am attempting to load a class object from some compiled class file sitting in my Desktop dir.

I am feeding in two arguments to main in my program which uses `URLClassLoader` to get an instance of a class from a compiled file `TheClassToLoad.class`.

I have, in Main of the classLoading program: `(args[0] is for something unrelated)`

```
String classFile_FilePath = args[1];
String className = args[2];
URL classUrl = new URL(classFile_FilePath);
URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{classUrl});
```

When running this program from the shell while in the project directory:

`Me:ClassLoadingProgramRootDir Me$ java com.company.Main argZero file:///Users/Me/Desktop/ TheClassToLoad.class`

I find a raised exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TheClassToLoad.class

So, there is a file `TheClassToLoad.class` in `Desktop/` yet `URLClassLoader` raises an exception without providing the detail I need to debug the situation.

I am new to Java and am aware that class paths like `com.company.Class` is often needed to refer to a class's true class name based on package directory structure.  However, in this case, I am simply requested that `URLClassLoader` give me an instance of the Class Object for an arbitrary compiled class file sitting somewhere on a machine.

Comment: If your class has a 'package' statement, you need to respect it when you try to load and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For URLClassLoader, the URL should be of the directory containing the class+package structure, not the class file itself.  In your case, it should be `file:///Users/Me/Desktop/`.

The argument to loadClass should be the name of the class, not the name of the class file.  In your case, it should be `TheClassToLoad`.

If the class is in a package (e.g., `my.pkg.TheClassToLoad`), then you should use that class name as the argument to loadClass, and the URL for URLClassLoader should still be the root of the package structure (e.g., `file:///Users/Me/Desktop` if the file is `file:///Users/Me/Desktop/my/pkg/TheClassToLoad.class`).

Comment: thank you, not using the "fully specifying" class name was the root cause